# How to fetch async data after componentWillMount deprecated?

Tags: react-native

componentWillMount will be removed from the future release of React Native. My app needs to fetch async API data from the server before rendering, then how to do it? The constructor can't be async. Or I have to use `promise().then` in constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use componentDidMount.

Because of the nature of async events in JavaScript, when you kick off an API call, the browser goes back to doing other work in the meantime. When React is rendering a component, it doesn’t wait for componentWillMount to finish whatever it started.

So componentWillMount over componentDidMount wasn't probably giving you any advantages anyways.

Comment: That is what I am doing now and leave the async API data fetch in `componentDidMount`. But in rendering the API data is needed for child component as props. I am wondering if componentDidMount is too late for rendering and will cause error in child component.or rendering itself. Or I need to prepare the child component to handle `undefined` props.

Comment: There is props `undefined` error in child component and I am wondering if this is related to the unavailability of the async API data when rendering.

Comment: Instead of handling undefined I would define an initial state. If you are waiting for a list of element for example, init this.state = {mylist: [] } in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to use ComponentDidMount instead. The fact that the component is rendered without data is best handled by using a `loading` flag in your state.

Comment: How this `loading` flag is being used? any code example would be appreciated.

Comment: So what I had in mind, and I'm not sure this is the best solution, is to have boolean state loaded, which defaults to false, and set to true after your async calls return. Rendering of subcomponents is then conditional on this state being true. If not, some sort of "Loading.." message could be shown.
So, in the constructor: `this.setState({loaded: false})`. In render: `return {this.state.loaded ? <SubComponent propA={this.state.propaA}> : Loading..}`
EDIT: hong develop gave you a more complete example below.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should use loading because it means we have to work on the data before the screen is visible.

example.js

```js
...
this.state={
     loading: false
}
....

async ComponentDidMount() {
     ....
     await your code
     ....
    this.setState({
      loading: true
    });
}

...

render{
   if(this.state.loading === false){
     <View style={[styles.container, styles.horizontal]}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
      </View>
   return(...);
  }
...


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  horizontal: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    padding: 10
  }
})
```